# CiviContribute link to database error

Tags: civicontribute

I recently moved our CiviCRM database to a new host and I'm getting a "DB Error: unknown error" on when testing the payment processing. Have a missed a configuration step?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if triggers aren't stripped from the db dump before you read it in to your db. This requires running something like

```
perl -pi -e 's#\/\*\!5001[7|3].*?`[^\*]*\*\/##g' dumpfile.sql
```

Where "dumpfile" needs replacing with the name of your db dump.

Answer (score 1):

Try after rebuilding menu and triggers

```
http://yourdomain.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Great. Did my answer helped in any case?